# Singular or Plural setting to a variable. PHP

Tags: php, variables, singular

There are a lot of questions explaining how to echo a singular or plural variable, but none answer my question as to how one sets a variable to contain said singular or plural value.

I would have thought it would work as follows:

```
$bottom="You have favourited <strong>$count</strong> " . $count == 1 ? 'user':'users';
```

This however does not work.

Can someone advise how I achieve the above?

Comment: Explain the outcome a bit more detailed than "it does not work".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ternary operator and string concatenation quirk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317383/ternary-operator-and-string-concatenation-quirk)

Comment: mario, I believe his problem is $bottom is always equal to only 'users' regardless of the ternary operation and concatenation

Comment: This link contains the most usable function i could find http://www.kavoir.com/2011/04/php-class-converting-plural-to-singular-or-vice-versa-in-english.html

Comment: Symfony now offers a the Inflector component converts English words between their singular and plural forms.
https://symfony.com/doc/master/components/inflector.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will solve your issue, thanks to mario and [Ternary operator and string concatenation quirk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317383/ternary-operator-and-string-concatenation-quirk)

```
$bottom = "You have favourited <strong>$count</strong> " . ($count == 1 ? 'user':'users');
```

Answer (score 38):

You can try this function I wrote:

```
/**
 * Pluralizes a word if quantity is not one.
 *
 * @param int $quantity Number of items
 * @param string $singular Singular form of word
 * @param string $plural Plural form of word; function will attempt to deduce plural form from singular if not provided
 * @return string Pluralized word if quantity is not one, otherwise singular
 */
public static function pluralize($quantity, $singular, $plural=null) {
    if($quantity==1 || !strlen($singular)) return $singular;
    if($plural!==null) return $plural;

    $last_letter = strtolower($singular[strlen($singular)-1]);
    switch($last_letter) {
        case 'y':
            return substr($singular,0,-1).'ies';
        case 's':
            return $singular.'es';
        default:
            return $singular.'s';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
pluralize(4, 'cat'); // cats
pluralize(3, 'kitty'); // kitties
pluralize(2, 'octopus', 'octopii'); // octopii
pluralize(1, 'mouse', 'mice'); // mouse
```

There's obviously a lot of exceptional words that this function will not pluralize correctly, but that's what the `$plural` argument is for :-)

Take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals) to see just how complicated pluralizing is!

Comment: @Francesco Sure it does. Usage: `pluralize(3, 'Ranch', 'Ranches')`. The 3rd argument is only optional for the most basic words.

Answer (score 27):

You might want to look at the [gettext extension](http://php.net/gettext). More specifically, it sounds like `ngettext()` will do what you want: it pluralises words correctly as long as you have a number to count from.

```
print ngettext('odor', 'odors', 1); // prints "odor"
print ngettext('odor', 'odors', 4); // prints "odors"
print ngettext('%d cat', '%d cats', 4); // prints "4 cats"
```

You can also make it handle translated plural forms correctly, which is its main purpose, though it's quite a lot of extra work to do.

Comment: actually it would be `printf(ngettext('%d cat', '%d cats', 4), 4); // prints "4 cats"`

Comment: That's not cool in combination with printf. Maybe PHP has something new today? :-)

Comment: This answer is not correct. `ngettext` is a plural version of `gettext`; essentially, this is a transation function; in many cases this is not appropriate solution.

Answer (score 7):

The best way IMO is to have an array of all your pluralization rules for each language, i.e. `array('man'=>'men', 'woman'=>'women');` and write a pluralize() function for each singular word.

You may want to take a look at the CakePHP inflector for some inspiration.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Utility/Inflector.php

Comment: That link is currently dead; source can be found here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/c2f298a8b7b461584dfdbe6a1c3feb81ba47e525/lib/Cake/Utility/Inflector.php

Answer (score 6):

Enjoy: https://github.com/ICanBoogie/Inflector

> Multilingual inflector that transforms words from singular to plural,
>   underscore to camel case, and more.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to go down the route of writing your own pluralize function then you might find this algorithmic description of pluralisation helpful:

http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/Plurals.html

Or the much easier approach would probably be to use one of the ready-made pluralize functions available on the Internet:

<strike>http://www.eval.ca/2007/03/03/php-pluralize-method/</strike>

Answer (score 1):

For `$count = 1`:

```
    "You have favourited <strong>$count</strong> " . $count == 1 ? 'user' : 'users';
=>               "You have favourited <strong>1</strong> 1" == 1 ? 'user' : 'users';
=>                                                        1 == 1 ? 'user' : 'users';
=>                                                          true ? 'user' : 'users';
// output: 'user'
```

The PHP parser (rightly) assumes everything to the left of the question mark is the condition, unless you change the order of precedence by adding in parenthesis of your own (as stated in other answers).

Answer (score 1):

Custom, transparent and extension-free solution. 
Not  sure about its speed.

```
/**
 * Custom plural
 */
function splur($n,$t1,$t2,$t3) {
    settype($n,'string');
    $e1=substr($n,-2);
    if($e1>10 && $e1<20) { return $n.' '.$t3; } // "Teen" forms
    $e2=substr($n,-1);
    switch($e2) {
        case '1': return $n.' '.$t1; break;
        case '2': 
        case '3':
        case '4': return $n.' '.$t2; break;
        default:  return $n.' '.$t3; break;
    }
}
```

Usage in Ukrainian / Russian:

```
splur(5,'сторінка','сторінки','сторінок') // 5 сторінок
splur(4,'сторінка','сторінки','сторінок') // 4 сторінки
splur(1,'сторінка','сторінки','сторінок') // 1 сторінка
splur(12,'сторінка','сторінки','сторінок') // 12 сторінок

splur(5,'страница','страницы','страниц') // 5 страниц
splur(4,'страница','страницы','страниц') // 4 страницы
splur(1,'страница','страницы','страниц') // 1 страница
splur(12,'страница','страницы','страниц') // 12 страниц
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `$count < 2` because `$count` can also be `0`

```
$count =1;
$bottom = sprintf("You have favourited <strong>%d %s</strong>", $count, ($count < 2 ? 'user' : 'users'));
print($bottom);
```

Output

```
You have favourited 1 user
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it.

```
$usersText = $count == 1 ? "user" : "users";
$bottom = "You have favourited <strong>" . $count . "</strong> " , $usersText;
```

Comment: oh, I see what you were trying to accomplish.  I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel, Str class has plural helper funcion:

```
use Str;
Str::plural('str');
```

Or you may use Pluralizer class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer;
Pluralizer::plural('str')
```