# Calling sqlsrv_connect leads to 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: sql-server, php-7, internal-server-error, sqlsrv

I am running on:

- Windows Server 2016 64-bit
- MSSQL Server 2016 on the same server
- PHP 7.1
- IIS 10

I have:

- Made sure I can connect to my SQL using the credentials supplied in the codes below.
- Installed [SQL Server Driver from for PHP from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20098), and chose SQLSRV40
- Added extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll and extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll to /ext folder.
- edited my php.ini and added extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll and extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll and restarted the server.

The following are my code to establish connection:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$db, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); 

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{ //Will not execute. As such, I have no idea what error(s) am I getting
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Executing phpinfo() does not show the sqlsrv. However, executing the following code will display a YES.

```
echo "Did it load? " . extension_loaded('php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll') ? "YES" : "NO";
```

I have worked on this for 2 days, and have followed many forums suggestions, and I have no idea what to try anymore. Would appreciate any advise from you experts! :)

**Update 1:**

I modified the codes below, and it shows a NO.

```
echo "Did it load? " . (extension_loaded('sqlsrv') ? "YES" : "NO");
echo "Did it load? " . (extension_loaded('pdo_sqlsrv') ? "YES" : "NO");
```

I don't understand why is it not installed correctly where the dll has already been put inside the extension folder, and specified inside php.ini as I stated earlier.

Comment: `extension_loaded()` expects the *name* of the extension not the dll file name... so it should be `extension_loaded('sqlsrv')` or `extension_loaded('pdo_sqlsrv')`. Also your test will always display `YES`, you need to wrap the ternary expression in parenthesis [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1317385/3760604).

Comment: @ImClarky Oh no... I have replaced it with just extension name, and added parenthesis. Now, the strings are displaying correctly and it shows a NO. Why is it NO? I have already put the dll inside the extension folder and added it into my php.ini. What else am I missing?

Comment: have a look at [this answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41893883/3760604). The OP seems to be having the same issue as yourself.

Comment: It worked!! You can either post this as answer or I'll update my post to update to your suggested post! :)