# Driver for sqlsrv 4.0 doesn't apper on phpinfo()

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

I need help with Microsoft driver for mssql 4.0. I use `php 7.1`, `win'2012 x64`, `mssql 2008 R2` and installed `odbc driver 13` as it is described in documentation and copyed all dlls in `ext` folder. In `php.ini` I added:

```
 extension_dir = "c:\inetpub\php\ext"

 extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
```

Restarted IIS.
And still after calling `phpinfo()` I can't see sqlsrv.

Maybe I missed something in php.ini?

Comment: Did you also install the client software. The PHP extension just connects PHP to the client libraries

Comment: Do you mean mssql? Yes, 2008 R2...

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: Yep, I use version 4.0

Comment: Im not 100% sure, but from roaming the github issues ([an example](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/255)), it appears that the drivers from the Microsoft website don't work with PHP 7.1 (despite what it says on the system requirements). You might want to try one of  [the latest sqlsrv binaries (v4.1.5)](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/4.1.5-Windows). See if that solves your issue

Comment: @ImClarky you are a genious! Please post your commen as an answer! It worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking through some of the [issues posted on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=php%207.1) it appears that the drivers supplied from the Microsoft website are currently incompatible with PHP 7.1, despite the System Requirements on the page claiming:

> Version 4.0 supports PHP 7.0+ on Windows and Linux

---

The latest binaries for the sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv drivers can be found through the [official GitHub repositiory](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql) with the latest* being [v4.1.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/4.1.5-Windows) (released 19 Jan 2017). Download the .zip related to your PHP version.

<sup>* Latest at time of posting</sup>