# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in XAMPP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server with PHP, but unfortunately it fails with calling the function at self. I installed the drivers (DLL), as well a the driver from this site: https://www.microsoft.com/de-ch/download/details.aspx?id=36434

I am receiving the following message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in ....
```

I running a local server with XAMPP with the newest PHP version 7.1.1.

**UPDATE:**

I checked if the extension is loaded in PHP:

```
var_dump(extension_loaded ("php_sqlsrv_7_nts"));
```

But it gives me a `bool(false)` back.

Comment: did u reset the server?

Comment: Do you mean a simple restart? Yes I also have done that.

Comment: Yes thats what I meant.... this will help u there was a smilar problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736601/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-in-c-xampp-htdocs

Comment: Are you using sqlsrv 4.0 (downloaded from Microsoft's website)? If so, [see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41893883/3760604)

Comment: @ImClarky Yes I downloaded the 4.0 version. Now I also downgraded to php version 7.0 but it doesn't work as well. I don't have any idea why I get this error.

Comment: Also, as an aside, `extension_loaded()` should pass the *extension name* not the file name. So in this case it would be `extension_loaded("sqlsrv")`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the MSSQL extension first and enable them. The is not working out of the box. What you have in your example is the ODBC driver but you need the PHP Extension in No Thread Safe Mode for your PHP-Version.

It's a bit complicated to find the correct extensions. Otherwise you can try to connect over ODBC but that make all a bit more complicated.

Try this:

https://learninglaravel.net/microsoft-drivers-for-php-7-for-sql-server-is-now-available

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already done this. I added it to the ext folder and registered it in the php.ini file.

Comment: Can you check if the Extension is loaded? It's possible that there are differents to PHP 7.1 and it's not working. And be sure that you use the Not Thread Safe version sorry my fault.