# Implement php expression in html string

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner in PHP and I have a such code.

```
<?php foreach ($statuses as $status) { ?>
    <div class="dropdown-item">
       <span data-status="<?php echo $status['id'] ?>" class="dropdown-item__sub <?php echo ($last_ticket['status'] ?? '') == $status['status'] ? ' active' : '' ?>"><?php echo $status['status'] ?></span>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Is it possible to write this expression in variable ? Like this ..

```
 $html .= '<span data-status=' . $status['id'] . ' class=' . 'dropdown-item__sub ' . ($last_ticket['status'] ?? '') == $status['status'] ? ' active' : ''  . '/>' . $status['status']. '</span>';
```

I try different way and it dose not work right.

Comment: Ok so what is wrong with it? Explain exactly what you wanted, and exactly what happened instead. "does not work" doesn't tell us anything useful about your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ternary operator and string concatenation quirk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317383/ternary-operator-and-string-concatenation-quirk)

Comment: P.S. the answer to "is it possible" is "yes you can", but you just have to do it right

Comment: You have also left out all the double quotes for the HTML attributes.

Comment: ADyson, at final result I have empty data statuses and class 'active' dose not added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$html .= '<span data-status="' . $status['id'] . '" class="' . 'dropdown-item__sub ' . (($last_ticket['status'] ?? '') == $status['status'] ? ' active' : '')  . '"/>' . $status['status']. '</span>';
```

You needed to

a) make sure there are double-quotes around the HTML attributes, and

b) put brackets round your ternary operator to ensure the precedence of the operators is as you need it

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f6135a1c3aaa88017857b2630879ff643a34822

Answer (score 0):

don't forget the '""'(double quote) on each attribute.

```
$html .= '<span data-status="' . $status['id'] . '" class="' . 'dropdown-item__sub ' . ($last_ticket['status'] ?? '') == $status['status'] ? ' active' : ''  . '/>"' . $status['status']. '</span>';
```

Comment: Renz Tulagan, could show example with my code please?

Comment: Result in browser look like this..  unfortunately not correct  <div class="dropdown-item">/&gt;"Open</div>

Comment: I did no see span inside div in browser.